# How do I add multiple custom XIBs to a scrollview programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have several XIBs that I want to add to a scrollview programmatically. However, when I add them using addSubview they are all shown on top of each other as the origin is always set to 0,0.

Is there a clean way of adding multiple XIBs whilst ensuring they are laid out properly and not on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

In your main view controller that contains your scroll view you can do this in Swift:

```
let leftView = LeftViewController(nibName: "LeftViewController", bundle: nil)

self.addChildViewController(leftView)
self.scrollView.addSubview(leftView.view)
leftView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

let middleView = MiddleViewController(nibName: "MiddleViewController", bundle: nil)

var frame1 = middleView.view.frame
frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width 
middleView.view.frame = frame1

self.addChildViewController(middleView)
self.scrollView.addSubview(middleView.view)
middleView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

let rightView = RightViewController(nibName: "RightViewController", bundle: nil)

var frame2 = rightView.view.frame
frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
rightView.view.frame = frame2

self.addChildViewController(rightView)
self.scrollView.addSubview(rightView.view)
rightView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)  

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3,     self.view.frame.size.height - 22)
```

Note: The -22 is to account for the status bar.

Credit for this solution goes to: https://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/4/2/uipageviewcontroller-in-swift-xcode-62-ios-82-tutorial